# Add Examples through Docstring to APISpec

Tags: python, flask, swagger, openapi

I have tried to add examples to my APISpec in my Flask application so that it is easily viewable in Swagger UI.  However, I can't seem to get it without hardcoding the entire example into the docstring.  I know that in the APISpec, I can add an example as a component, but I can't reference it the same way as I can a schema.

My blueprint code looks like this

```
@blueprint_one.route('/route1', methods=["POST"])
def func():
    """
    ---
    post:
      description: acknowledges receipt of request
      requestBody:
          required: true
          content:
            application/json:
              schema: Request
              examples:
                Example1:
                  $ref: #/components/examples/Example1
    """
    <some stuff>
    return <some json>
```

and my api spec has

```
spec.components.example('Example1', {
  "field1": "one",
  "field2": 2
})
```

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$ref`?

Comment: That did not work